# differentiation $f$ and $g$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f
>  \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by:
>
> $   f(x) =   \begin{cases}
>                                    g(x) & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\
>                                    -g(x) & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$}    \end{cases} $ 
> For each $x$ with $g(x)=0$ show
>   that $f'(x)=0$ iff $g'(x)=0$.

This is what I have tried:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)=0$. 
Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}-\{x\}$ with $\{x_{n}\} \to x$.

(1) Assume $g'(x)=0$. Show $f'(x)=0$.
Case I: $x_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

 Let $\epsilon \gt 0$. Since $g$ is differentiable we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n \gt N$ we have $\mid\frac{g(x_{n})-0}{x_{n}-x}-0\mid \lt \epsilon$.

 Then $\mid{\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x)}{x_{n}-x}}-0\mid=\mid\frac{g(x_{n})-0}{x_{n}-x}-0\mid \lt \epsilon$.

Case II: $x_{n} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

 Let $\epsilon \gt 0$. Since $g$ is differentiable we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n \gt N$ we have $\mid\frac{g(x_{n})-0}{x_{n}-x}-0\mid \lt \epsilon$.

 Then $\mid{\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x)}{x_{n}-x}}-0\mid=\mid\frac{-g(x_{n})+0}{x_{n}-x}-0\mid=\mid\frac{g(x_{n})-0}{x_{n}-x}-0\mid \lt \epsilon$.

 Both cases imply that $f'(x)=0$.

(2) Assume $f'(x)=0.$ Show $g'(x)=0.$

Since $f$ is differentiable at those $x$ with $f(x)=0$, $\{\frac{g(x_{n})-0}{x_{n}-x}\}=\{\frac{f(x_{n})-0}{x_{n}-x}\} \to f'(x)=0$.

I've tried to show all my steps so it was clear what I was thinking. I'm not too confident with what I did and was hoping I could get some feedback. Does it look all right? Is there any way to tidy it up a bit or a shorter way to do it? Thanks =)

Comment: What happens if the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has rational $x_{2n}$ and irrational $x_{2n+1}$? Is it Case I or Case II?

Comment: Right, I was trying to show the distance. So I was considering any given term $x_{n}$ of the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ (which as you pointed out can have $x_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $\notin \mathbb{Q} $)

Comment: In the proof of (1), $g(x)=f(x)=0$ so that $|f(x_n)-f(x)|=|g(x_n)-g(x)|$ regardless of $x_n$ being rational or not. So you can make the proof simple.

Answer (score 1):

$-|g(x)| \le f(x) \le |g(x)|$

If it exists, $f'(x) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

When $g(x) = 0$

$f'(x) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h)}{h}$

$-\frac {|g(x+h)|}{h} \le \frac {f(x+h)}{h} \le \frac {|g(x+h)|}{h}$

and if $g'(x) = 0$
then $\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {g(x+h)}{h} = \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {|g(x+h)|}{h}= \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {-|g(x+h)|}{h} = 0$

$f'(x) = 0$ by the squeeze theroem.

Comment: I can only use what I've seen in class :( so unfortunately I can't describe $f'(x)$ as the limit when h tends to 0 ....